# C# cannot delete dll files with a new process

Tags: c#, process, delete-file, access-denied

let's say there are two executable files, Exe1 and Exe2.
i ran Exe1 and in Exe1 i called

```
    Process.Start(info);
```

to start Exe2 and then call

```
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

to kill Exe1, once Exe2 was started i want to delete the Exe1 file and replace Exe1 with a new version Exe1, but when i call File.Delete an exception was thrown tell me access is denied. 
can someone give me some ideas how to delete Exe1 file without exception? thanks

Comment: Execute as admin

Comment: At a guess, the old application hasn't finished running at the point where you try to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake, the exe2 and exe1 refer to a same dll and i tried to delete that shared dll. thank you guys for your help